# Python - replace conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

In Anaconda [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#), I've learned that you can:

`conda create --name myenv` and

`conda remove --name myenv --all` enviroments.

but then I've learned that only with `conda create --name myenv anaconda` <--- you have all default packages installed.

so, if I want to keep the name `myenv`:

can I **replace** `myenv` with a new one using the same name (adding all default packages on top of that), or do I necessarily have to remove `myenv` and create a new one from scratch?

Comment: If you want to *replace*, as far as I know, there's no command. However, if you want to *append*, you can do `conda install -n myenv anaconda` and it will install all the packages specified in the `anaconda` meta-package

Comment: I would accept your `append` comment as an answer, if you want.

Comment: Too late! Oh well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just activate your environment.

On Windows:

```
activate myenv
```

On Unix/Mac OS X:

```
source activate myenv
```

and install all packages.

```
conda install anaconda
```